Secure Channels in Ideal World
In the real world ideal world paradigm for proving security of a multiparty protocol we consider secure channels between honest parties and the TTP (trusted third party).
1.What does secure channel mean?
2.Is it same as pairwise channels between parties in real world?
3.Can adversary eavesdrop on the messages sent over secure channel or is eavesdropping also not allowed when we say secure channels?

I'm rereading the question after writing an answer for it, but "the real world ideal world paradigm" is unclear to me.

By trusted third party, I am assuming you mean the non-existant third party that we compare security against. That is, an MPC protocol that securely allows you to compute some function $f$ is equivalent to all parties sending their inputs to a "trusted third party" who computes $f$ on the inputs and returns the result. You can assume that the honest parties and the trusted third party communications via "a secure channel". In this case, the third party doesn't really exist but in the metaphor we assume the honest parties can security communicate with the TTP.
Various models interpret this slightly differently but in the common case you can think about it is the honest parties can simply call the TTP via a function call. Like say your MPC protocol makes use of an algorithm $F$. Clearly each party can just locally call $F(x)$ and the code implementing $F$ will be executed. The same for the TTP, its some block box that each party has access to. They can simply invoke that block box on their chosen input, i.e. $TTP(x)$, and the TTP starts executing whatever it is suppose to compute.
There are other models such as asynchronous that allow that adversary to delay when $TTP(x)$ starts executing or when it returns a result. This is intended to model the adversary being able to intercept messages on the internet and delay or delete them. However, MPC protocols rarely use this model.
Ideally, if it's not the former def. the paper should give a formal definition for what an ideal private channel is.

I'll be happy to help you with your questions.

In the context of cryptography and secure communication, a secure channel refers to a communication channel that provides confidentiality, integrity, and authenticity of the messages transmitted over it. This means that any message sent over a secure channel is protected from unauthorized access, modification, or tampering, and the recipient can be assured that the message comes from the claimed sender.

In the real world, pairwise channels between parties are not necessarily secure. In fact, most communication channels, such as the internet, are inherently insecure, meaning that an adversary can potentially intercept, read, or modify the messages being transmitted. Secure channels, on the other hand, are abstract concepts that assume a certain level of security guarantees, which may not be achievable in practice without additional measures such as encryption, authentication, and other security protocols.

When we say secure channels, it implies that eavesdropping is not allowed. A secure channel is designed to prevent any unauthorized party, including an adversary, from intercepting or reading the messages being transmitted. This means that even if an adversary tries to eavesdrop on the communication, they will not be able to access the contents of the messages or modify them in any way. The secure channel ensures that the messages remain confidential and authentic, and only the intended recipient can access them.


